# Добавления Column

Tags: c#, access

У меня в С№ форме есть dataGridView1, к которому подключена база данных access.

У меня сразу два вопроса:

1. Мне нужно добавить новый Column (Столбец). Я пробовал через настройки самого грида add column. Но если так сделать, то именно тот столбец не сохраняется. Как мне сделать так, чтобы он добавился и в грид, и  саму таблицу в access и сохранялся.
2. Тот же грид. Пробовал заполнить его через текст боксы вот таким кодом:

`dataGridView1.Rows.Add(name, avtor, otz, stat, janr);`

Но выдает ошибку.

Строки нельзя программным способом добавить в коллекцию строк DataGridView, если элемент управления привязан к данным.

Как же мне реализовать функцию заполнения из текст боксов?

Answer (score 1):

1. Не совсем понятен смысл манипуляций. Добавьте нужное поле в саму БД да и всё.
2. Тоже самое добавляйте запись в БД, а НЕ Row в dataGridView.